# Set the background image in blur effect in android app

Tags: android, imageview

Im trying to get my background image on the list view blurred, but I tried following the tutorials and it does not work. Anyone please advise, thanks.

main activity.java

```
public class IngredientCategoryMain extends Activity {

ListView list;
String[] title;
CategoryImageAdapter adapter;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ingredient_category_main);

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    title = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
    adapter=new CategoryImageAdapter(this, mStrings, title);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    list.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}

public View.OnClickListener listener=new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
};

public void onItemClick(int mPosition) {
    String tempValues = title[mPosition];
    Toast.makeText(IngredientCategoryMain.this, "Click on image "+tempValues+" to enter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

private String[] mStrings={
        "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/07/08/14/33/breads-387544_960_720.jpg",
        "http://mtbev.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Bottles.jpg",
        "https://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7023/6548962149_7a9fdd9cf4_b.jpg",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Culinary_fruits_front_view.jpg",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Indian_Spices.jpg",
        "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/13/17/21/raw-1138562_960_720.jpg",
        "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2010/12/13/09/51/seed-1716_960_720.jpg",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Rice_grains_(IRRI).jpg",
        "http://www.stock-free.org/images/Thanksgiving-Stock-Free-Image-08112015-image-239.jpg",
        "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/10/01/18/34/dips-58738_960_720.jpg",
        "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/19/00/18/seafood-165220_960_720.jpg",
        "https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2877/10866943666_471d9f2845_b.jpg"
};


}
```

xml file where I designed the listview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#f7338b"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="#80ffffff" />
```

and listview.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.cassieleong.delishcart.IngredientCategoryMain"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_ingredient_category_main"
android:background="#fde7e7">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/appicon"/>
```

Comment: Not a complete answer but it might help

In a frame layout keep two imageviews
first the imageView you want to blurr than the next
jst give transparency to the next image
so that your image is seen behind the other transparent image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently came across Renderscript API.

```
//Set the radius of the Blur. Supported range 0 < radius <= 25
private static final float BLUR_RADIUS = 25f;

public Bitmap blur(Bitmap image) {
if (null == image) return null;

Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image);
final RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(this);
Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, image);
Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, outputBitmap);

//Intrinsic Gausian blur filter
ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);
return outputBitmap;
}
```

Use the above code snippet in the image view as shown below.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.nature);
Bitmap blurredBitmap = blur(bitmap);
imageView.setImageBitmap(blurredBitmap);
```

Dont forget to add below lines in build.gradle file

```
renderscriptTargetApi 18
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

Reference : 
http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-create-bitmap-blur-effect-in-android-using-renderscript

Comment: Not works for .jpgs or .jpegs. Only works with .pngs