# Blur effect on background

Tags: android, image

I need to show something like this in an ImageView

Do you know a method to set an image in an ImageView like so?

[image: This]

Image in background is bluerd and image on it is with blur effect

```
ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

**I need put in bitmap my picture and fuzzy picture in background.**

this only sets one picture and I need put some fuzzy background

I know how put only one image in 100% quality.
But I don't know how set the background image to this picture.

I don't know how this "filter" name and I could not Google for that.

Comment: your question is bit unclear what do you want to achieve mention that in a single line again

Comment: You want to **blur** the background image. That's all you need to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/36193733:

> I recently came across Renderscript API.
>
> ```
> //Set the radius of the Blur. Supported range 0 < radius <= 25
> private static final float BLUR_RADIUS = 25f;
>
> public Bitmap blur(Bitmap image) {
> if (null == image) return null;
>
> Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image);
> final RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(this);
> Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, image);
> Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, outputBitmap);
>
> //Intrinsic Gausian blur filter
> ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
> theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
> theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
> theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
> tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);
> return outputBitmap;
> }
> ```
>
> Use the above code snippet in the image view as shown below.
>
> ```
> ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
> Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.nature);
> Bitmap blurredBitmap = blur(bitmap);
> imageView.setImageBitmap(blurredBitmap);
> ```
>
> Dont forget to add below lines in build.gradle file
>
> ```
> renderscriptTargetApi 18
> renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
> ```

Comment: There's a better alternative to this approach: **fastblur**

Comment: Consider taking a course on googling. http://trickyandroid.com/advanced-blurring-techniques/

Answer (score 0):

You can use View Pager and Add ImageView in each page, that way you can switch between images,

Comment: no this question is not about it.. I cant find good pictures.. only this :) 

I need picture and fuzzy picture in background on the same imageview

Answer (score -1):

Set your fuzzy/blurry image as the background, using

```
     android:background = "@drawable/myFuzzyImage"
```

Set your clear image as you would normally, just like you have, using the setImageBitmap, or using an ImageView in the xml file of your activity layout.

Comment: and how build from my image fuzzy image?

Comment: Add the image to your drawable folder. In the main layout of your activity, <LinearLayout android:background = "@drawable/myFuzzyImage">.